# List all possible localization names in shell32.dll (or any other dll with this)

Tags: windows, dll

I have interest in customize some folders on my system via desktop.ini and the `LocalizedResourceName` property, but i dont know how i could list all possible values/strings contained in Windows dlls.

For example, the Saved Games special folder have its `LocalizedResourceName` pointed to `@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21814`, and i want to list all the other localization resources within this dll.

How can I display all of this data?

Comment: Asking for software is off-topic. I've tweaked your question slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the strings you want aren't "hard coded" someplace (a *generally* safe assumption for Microsoft software), you can use a program like [Resources Extract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html) from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net) to get at strings that are stored as resources within an executable or DLL.

FWIW: The string you mention in your question, `LocalizedResourceName`, actually exists in `wmp.dll` in the System32 folder.

Also, you'll find similar tools by doing a Google search for "windows resource extractor."

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/01/18/1487464.html) I found a very helful article.
The only thing you need is this [LoadLibraryEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) and [LoadString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadstringw).
The code uses the SHGetLocalizedName too, but I found out, that it only reads the corresponding desktop.ini.

I created an app to collect all the librarys (.dll) and strings in it, that are used by the myltiple desktop.ini files in my system and will publish them here for german DE-de:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\system\wab32res.dll   10100                  Contacts Kontakte
C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll                           12385                     Links Favoritenleiste
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                            8964               Recycle Bin Papierkorb
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                            9031                  Searches Suchvorgänge
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21769                   Desktop Desktop
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21770                 Documents Dokumente
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21779                  Pictures Bilder
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21781             Program Files Programme
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21790                     Music Musik
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21791                    Videos Videos
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21796                 Favorites Favoriten
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21798                 Downloads Downloads
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21799            Public Desktop Öffentlicher Desktop
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21801          Public Documents Öffentliche Dokumente
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21802           Public Pictures Öffentliche Bilder
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21803              Public Music Öffentliche Musik
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21804             Public Videos Öffentliche Videos
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21808          Public Downloads Öffentliche Downloads
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21810                     Links Links
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21813                     Users Benutzer
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21814               Saved Games Gespeicherte Spiele
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21816                    Public Öffentlich
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           21817       Program Files (x86) Programme (x86)
C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll                           50691          Public Libraries Bibliotheken
C:\Windows\system32\windows.storage.dll                   21824               Camera Roll Eigene Aufnahmen
C:\Windows\system32\windows.storage.dll                   21825                3D Objects 3D-Objekte
C:\Windows\system32\windows.storage.dll                   34583            Saved Pictures Gespeicherte Bilder
C:\Windows\system32\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll              23570     User Account Pictures Standardmäßige Profilbilder
C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll              38304    Public AccountPictures Öffentliche Profilbilder
```